# How can I run same test concurrently in testcafe to create a race condition?

Tags: javascript, testing, testcafe

I am trying to create a race condition, where the same test will run at the same time concurrently

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `testcafe` command to run the test, you can use the [`--concurrency` option](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#concurrency). If you use [`runner`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402641/reference/testcafe-api/runner), you can set concurrency using [the eponymous method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402658/reference/testcafe-api/runner/concurrency) or just create several `runner` objects and [`run`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402655/reference/testcafe-api/runner/run) them with `Promise.race`:

```js
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');

async function runTest(testcafe, src) {
    const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

    const failed = await runner
        .src(src)
        .browsers('chrome')
        .run();

    console.log('Tests failed: ' + failed);
}

(async function () {
    const testcafe = await createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338);

    try {
        await Promise.race([
            runTest(testcafe, './test1.js'),
            runTest(testcafe, './test2.js'),
            runTest(testcafe, './test3.js'),
        ])
    }
    finally {
        await testcafe.close();
    }
})()
```